# Get the name of a HTML file from a PHP script

Tags: php, html, filenames

I want to somehow check the name of HTML file which has a submit button which goes to 'updatecart.php', in this php file I wanted to do an IF statement such as:

updatecart.php - Pseudo code:

```
IF(calling HTML file == "book1.html"){

// INSERT BOOK1 DATA INTO DATABASE TABLE (SQL)

}

IF(calling HTML file == "book2.html"){

// INSERT BOOK2 DATA INTO DATABASE TABLE (SQL)

}
```

etc...

I basically have multiple HTML files which all have a form with action set to `action = "updatecart.php"` and I want to insert different data into the same database table depending on which page the form was submitted.

So I need to find the name of the HTML page from which the form was submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to use an input field `hidden` with value that you want to check.

Eg:

book1.html

```
<form action="updatecart.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="book1" />
</form>
```

book2.html

```
<form action="updatecart.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="filename" value="book2" />
</form>
```

And you can check it by,

```
<?php

$filename = $_POST['filename'];

if ($filename === 'book1') {
 // INSERT BOOK1 DATA INTO DATABASE TABLE (SQL)
} else if ($filename === 'book2') {
 // INSERT BOOK2 DATA INTO DATABASE TABLE (SQL)
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a reason why you left out `method = 'post'` in book2.html?

Comment: Sry! I forgot to put `method = 'post'` in book2.html. See the above updated one.

Comment: No problem, also the 3 equals `===` is new to me, I use `==`

Comment: You can find the difference b/w `===` and `==` from here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, to get the requesting page, but this is not always completely dependable.  A better way to go about this would be to put a hidden input unique to the particular page in that page's form and check that instead.